# Harmonic series (double)

Tags: summation, asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

I am wondering about the $\Theta$ class (i.e. asymptotic complexity) of the following:

> $$\sum^n_{i=1} \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{ij}$$

Since this is basically the harmonic series, applied twice, it seems to me that the answer is $\Theta(\log ^2 n)$. Is this correct?

Comment: what does $\log ^2 n$ mean?

Comment: No, what does "complexity" mean? If you just want asymptotics, then yes, your sum is obviously the same as $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{1\over i}\right)^2$.

Comment: I am a computer scientist analyzing the asymptotic complexity of an algorithm. I want only the \Theta class, yes, asymptotics. log^2 n means log n \times log n.

Comment: your summands split as a product, and more generally
$$ \sum_n \sum_m (a_n b_m ) = \left(\sum_n a_n\right) \left(\sum_m b_m \right) $$

Comment: Thank you. Why not post as an answer?